# Is there a Google Now command to toggle auto screen orientation?

Tags: google-now

Is there a Google Now voice command to toggle auto screen orientation (e.g. "Ok Google, enable screen rotation")?

I know there are commands to toggle Bluetooth or Wifi, but is there a command to change the screen orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There isn't an *official* Google Now commands list
- See this [recent reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/4qebru/ok_google_explore_over_150_google_now_voice/) post, where the OP has created this [web site](http://ok-google.io/) dedicated to known Google Now commands and their variations.
- There is **no command** for changing screen automation

Comment: You are right. I could do it by using 3rd party apps: Tasker and the AutoVoice Tasker plugin.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation I could not find a voice command. But this can be archived  by using a combination of Tasker and the AutoVoice Tasker plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to use Google Now launcher and the latest update of google now

source: http://www.clintonfitch.com/2016/02/how-to-enable-screen-rotation-in-google-now/

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I don't want to change the enable screen rotation In the Google Now Launcher, I want to use a voice command to toggle the screen rotation (e.g. "Ok Google, enable screen rotation").